# Display json data results from a form in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm trying to display the json data coming back from my script in a pop-up window and once the pop-up is opened each name will be a link in the pop-up that once clicked it will open another page in place of the parent, it should close the parent window as well.
My code gets the data, but the pop-pop doesn't show up. Here is my code sample.

CSS:

```
  .popup {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      display:none;
      position:fixed;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  }

  /* Inner */
  .popup-inner {
      max-width:700px;
      width:90%;
      padding:40px;
      position:absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
      box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
      border-radius:3px;
      background:#fff;
  }

  .popup-close {
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
      padding-top:4px;
      display:inline-block;
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      right:0px;
      transition:ease 0.25s all;
      -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
      transform:translate(50%, -50%);
      border-radius:1000px;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
      font-size:20px;
      text-align:center;
      line-height:100%;
      color:#fff;
  }

  .popup-close:hover {
      -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
      transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
      background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
      text-decoration:none;
  }
```

JS:

```
$("document").ready(function(){

  $('#myForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var datastring = $("#myForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "get_json.pl",
      data: datastring,

      success: function(data) {

    var stable =
      '<div class="popup-inner">'+
      ' <h2>Results</h2>'+
          ' <div>'+

      $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        stable+= '<p><a href="results_1.pl?name=' + value.name + '&gender=' + value.gender + ' "id="btnSend">Name: ' + value.name + '</a> | ' + 'Gender: ' + value.gender + '</p>';

    });

  stable += 
      ' </div>'+
          '<p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>'+
          '<a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>'+
      '</div>';

   var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
   $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
   e.preventDefault();

      $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
        e.preventDefault();
      });


   },
   error: function() {
    alert('Error handing data');
   }

   });

});
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Search by Name" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>


<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
</div>
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this, I solved my problem, here is the code, it might help someone. If there are any suggestions on improving the code, please let me know.

JS:

```
$("document").ready(function(){

  $('#myForm').submit(function(e){

   // To stop the default behavior, a # will be added to the URL in the address bar.
   e.preventDefault();

   var datastring = $("#myForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "get_json.pl",
      data: datastring,

      success: function(data) {

      var stable =
       '<div class="popup-inner">'+
       ' <h2>Results</h2>'+
          ' <div>';

      $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        stable+= '<p><a href="results_1.pl?name=' + value.name + '&gender=' + value.gender + ' "id="btnSend">Name: ' + value.name + '</a> | ' + 'Gender: ' + value.gender + '</p>';

    });

  stable += 
      ' </div>'+
          '<p><a data-popup-close="popup" href="#">Close</a></p>'+
          '<a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup" href="#">x</a>'+
      '</div>';

   // Popup will be called here and opended in the div below 
   $('#popup').append(stable).fadeIn(350);

      // This function will close the popup on click.
      $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {

        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('#'+targeted_popup_class).fadeOut(350);
    // Or use the id from the div below to close it.
    //$('#popup').fadeOut(350);
        e.preventDefault();

      });


   },
   error: function() {
    alert('Error handing data');
   }

   });

});
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This line appears to end with a + when you'd want a ;

```
var stable =
  '<div class="popup-inner">'+
  ' <h2>Results</h2>'+
  ' <div>';
```

Comment: I do need the + there, cause I am appending to the variable stable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You currently have a statement ending with an operator, which isn't valid: `var stable = '<div class="popup-inner">'+ ' <h2>Results</h2>'+ ' <div>'+`

Comment: The statement isn't ending there, if you look at the next line inside of the $.each there is this stable=+ which means that I am appending to the variable stable, it doesn't end till down where you can see this:  stable += 
       ' </div>'+
              '<p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>'+
              '<a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>'+
       '</div>';

Comment: But that isn't where my problem is, unless there is a better way to do this.

Comment: So that's not how you keep appending to the string.  You can still end the first statement with a semicolon and the next statement with `stable+=` will append to that string.  After you're done appending everything to `stable`, `console.log(stable)` to make sure it appears in the console as you want it to.

Comment: Yes it does, the code for the pop-up shows on the  console.log(stable), but it doesn't display.